# in html is possible to input excel spreadsheet of data and form a graph?

Tags: css, html, excel, graph

I want to create a program which allow in html to read excel data and form a graph but I do not know how to do it.

Any idea how to do it? Possible then could you send me a link I can look to start the project?

Comment: Yes but could not find !

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at  **js-xlsx**(https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) library using tha t you can parse excel files.

Comment: Hi thanks but looks like the link you provided me does not solve the problem as it does not create a chart or graph

Comment: for those things you have to code yourself. you can use D3(http://d3js.org/) for drawing charts and graphs .